# How do I solve the portability of WP_Error?

Tags: error-handling

I wrote a lot of code with the intention of it being usable not only in the WordPress space, but everywhere and because of that, I've been very, very against returning `WP_Errors` and resorted to only returning `bool` when something went wrong. Naturally, that's not enough because a boolean doesn't give you any context as to what went wrong.

Is there any library/way to bridge the gap between `WP_Error`s and something the whole PHP ecosystem understands? That is to say, if I take my code that's written mostly for WordPress and plug it into a non-WP environment, is there something that will guarantee it'll work when I return an `Error`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but you will need to separate the WordPress code into its own plugin. The other code should not require anything from WordPress, and instead return errors, exception objects or flags that make sense to the library code.

The WordPress plugin would use your library code and convert those errors, exception objects or flags to an instance of WP_Errors. This will provide a bridge or compatibility layer between your library code and WordPress. You could repeat this pattern for any other PHP content management system, like Joomla, etc.